# Why does the order of alternatives matter in regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RegexNoMatch {
    class Program {
        static void Main () {
            string input = "a foobar& b";
            string regex1 = "(foobar|foo)&?";
            string regex2 = "(foo|foobar)&?";
            string replace = "$1";
            Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(input, regex1, replace));
            Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(input, regex2, replace));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected output**

```
a foobar b
a foobar b
```

**Actual output**

```
a foobar b
a foobar& b
```

**Question**

Why does replacing not work when the order of "foo" and "foobar" in regex pattern is changed? How to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The regular expression engine tries to match the alternatives in the order in which they are specified. So when the pattern is `(foo|foobar)&?` it matches `foo` immediately and continues trying to find matches. The next bit of the input string is `bar& b` which cannot be matched.

In other words, because `foo` is part of `foobar`, there is no way `(foo|foobar)` will ever match `foobar`, since it will always match `foo` first.

Occasionally, this can be a very useful trick, actually. The pattern `(o|a|(\w))` will allow you to capture `\w` and `a` or `o` differently:

```
Regex.Replace("a foobar& b", "(o|a|(\\w))", "$2") // fbr& b
```

Comment: Why isn't regex greedy? I thought it is supposed to match the longest string it can match.

Comment: @Athari greediness applies to quantifiers, not to alternations.

Comment: Is there a way to force greediness for alternations, or do I have to sort alternations in reverse alphabetical order?

Comment: @Athari Alphabetical order makes no difference. Alternations should be sorted by the *broadest* pattern first, e.g. `foobar` is broader than `foo` because any string that matches `foo` will also match `foobar` (of course `foo(bar)?` is more sensible here). Unless you're trying to use the trick described in my updated answer.

Comment: In my real case, the list is quite long, so making regex more complex isn't worth it. I guess [this suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2395056/293099) solves my problem, as I need to match separate words.

Comment: @Athari Yes, if you want to match whole words only, `\b(…)\b` is the way to go.